# I need print out up to the N'th term and the N'th term give given that 1, 2, 5, 26, 677,.

Tags: c

> given that  1, 2, 5, 26, 677,...
>    such that the nth term of the series equals to
>   (n-1)th ^2 +1 and the first term of the series is 1.
>   Write a program using recursive function named f to compute the nth term.

I can't get anything to print out. How can i Fix this?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int f(int n)
{
if(n==1)
   {
   return 1;
   }
   else
   {
     return f((n-1)^2)+1;
   }

}


int main()
{
    int N,i;
    printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int u = f(N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
    printf("%d ",u);
    }


    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: I realize that a large part of the code that should be there is not in the code, like the given sequence I don't really understand how to use it

Comment: `(n-1)^2` is not the square of `n-1`. Another problem is that you need to square the value that is **returned** from the function. You do not want to square the value that you **pass** to the function. In general, you need to learn how to debug your code. You can either use a debugger, or just add a bunch of `printf`s to the code so you can see what the code is doing.

Comment: @user3386109 I can't comprehend how you relate n as the position of the array sequence that's already given to me how can I do that?

Comment: `f(1)` should be 1. Your code already does that. `f(2)` should be 2. Your code doesn't do that, and I already told you why. Once you fix `f(2)`, then you can move on to `f(3)=5`, `f(4)=26`, etc.

Comment: You need to call the function on each iteration.  Your code calls the function once and then prints the same value repeatedly.

Comment: Don't use scanf to read a parameter.  And don't use `int main()`.  It's not 1987.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way (IMO) to do this is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long
f(int n)
{
        return n == 1 ? 1 : f(n-1) * f(n-1) + 1;
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int n = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 2;
        for(int i=1; i < n; i++) {
                printf("%d: %ld\n", i, f(i));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

There are a lot of improvements that should be made above, but that gives the basic idea.  But it seems like you're trying to do something more along the lines of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long
f(int n)
{
        long r= 1;
        if(n > 1) {
                r = f(n-1);
                r = r * r + 1 ;
        }
        printf("%d: %ld\n", n, r);
        return r;
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int n = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 2;
        f(n);
        return 0;
}
```

You should probably include some error checking to prevent overflow and return non-zero from main if that happens, but that will depend on how you want to handle overflow.

Comment: Why is N in caps?

Comment: Just because the OP used that name.  It seems a little weird to me, too, but not too terrible.

Comment: You could point out convention is caps are you for the predecessor

Comment: That's a good thought.  I'll just change the name and mention it here in the comments.  Fully capitalized names are typically only used for the preprocessor.